# How to serve up logging files in a html page?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

We are using spring boot for our Web Service. The logging is implemented by using logback. The application is deployed in a Red Hat Linux box and now if we want to browse over the logs we don't want to look through the plain text version. There needs to be static html page to serve it up. I tried looking at the examples but no one tried for logging.

Answer (score 4):

[Spring Boot Admin](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin) is a separate application which offers admin features over any Spring Boot app. These featues include a `logfile-endpoint` which allows you to see and tail logfile(s) produced by a Spring Boot app. By default, that endpoint will provide access to the log file defined by the Spring Boot `logging.file` property and you can also configure a non Spring Boot managed logfile by defining the property: `endpoints.logfile.external-file`.

If that tool is not a runner then your options might be:

- [logviewer](https://github.com/aestasit/logviewer)
- Roll your own, for example ...

  - Use Commons IO [Tailer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html) to tail your file, via a file mount on the target server or remotely using [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) perhaps
  - Use a `SocketAppender` to emit log events from the server and consume those log events on the client side for display in the browser

Answer (score 0):

[Log Viewer](https://github.com/sevdokimov/log-viewer) solves this problem. It provides a web page to monitor logs on a server. Full access to the log file is available, not only tail. Filtering, highlighting is supported as well. No problem with big files.
The tool can be added to a spring boot application as a library and works inside the application, or can be run standalone.